# Facebook Ads API -> Displaying Campaigns

Tags: facebook

I am trying to show a list of all my facebook ad campaigns for the current day...

This code mostly works, except it only shows 24 of my campaigns... when I have over 100.

I am not sure why this would be... also not sure how to show for the current day stats... thanks for any help

```
<?php

$app_id='ID';
$app_secret='SECRET';
$access_token = 'TOKEN';

define('SDK_DIR', __DIR__ . '/..'); // Path to the SDK directory
$loader = include SDK_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();

use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdAccountFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCampaignFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;

$me = new AdUser('me');
$accounts = $me->getAdAccounts();

// Output account ID
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
  echo $account_id = $account->id;
   echo "----";
}

$account = new AdAccount($account_id);

$fields = array(
  AdCampaignFields::NAME,
  AdCampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
  AdCampaignFields::STATUS,
);

$campaigns = $account->getAdCampaigns($fields);
?>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#6699CC" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Campaign_id</th>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Campaign Name</th>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Status</th>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Impressions</th>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Clicks</th>
<th bgcolor="#336699" style="color:#FFF">Spent</th>
</tr>

<?PHP
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
//---------------------------------
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $campaign->id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $campaign->name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $campaign->campaign_group_status ?></td>

<?php

$fields = array (
        'impressions',
        'clicks',
        'spent',
);

$params = array (
    'date_preset'=>'yesterday',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id','actions','spend']",
);

$campaign = new AdCampaign($campaign->id);
$stats = $campaign->getStats($fields, $params);

foreach ($stats as $stat) {
        echo '<td>'.$stat->impressions. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$stat->clicks. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$stat->spent. '</td>';
}

//---------------------------------
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a param array to pass in.  In the example below I set the limit to 500.

```
$params = array(
    'time_interval' => array(
          'day_start' => array('year' =>'2015', 'month'=> '5', 'day'=>'1'),
          'day_stop' => array( 'year'=>'2015', 'month'=>'5', 'day'=>'31')
     ),
     'limit' => 500,
);
 $fields = array(
            AdCampaignFields::NAME,
            AdCampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
            AdCampaignFields::STATUS,
     );

$campaigns = $account->getAdCampaigns($fields,$params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue right now, so I am writing this as help to others.

You need to explicit say that you want to loop through whole result set (all result pages), and you doing it by setting `ImplicitFetch` to `true`. Example for you code :

```
$campaigns = $account->getAdCampaigns($fields);
...
$campaigns->setUseImplicitFetch(true); // set this before loop
...
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
```

Best regards,
Nikola